# Cannot use Haskell OpenGL on Linux

Tags: c, haskell, opengl, ffi

#### Edit:

My package [opengl-examples](https://github.com/stla/opengl-examples) works very well, so this is an issue with the FFI.

---

I wanted to try [my opengl-implicit package](https://github.com/stla/opengl-implicit) on another computer, namely a PC with Linux Ubuntu. The package correctly compiles. However when I run a graphics (from GHCi or from an executable) I get a list of errors (see below). The list of errors starts with

```
Error in `.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-11.2/8.2.2/bin/goursat': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00000000025bad90
```

Any idea what's happening ? Does that mean it is an error caused by the `free` function (which I use in my Haskell code) ?

```
:~/Work/Haskell/opengl-implicit$ .stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-11.2/8.2.2/bin/goursat
*** Goursat surface ***
    To quit, press q.
    Scene rotation:
        e, r, t, y, u, i
    Zoom: l, m
    Increase/decrease parameters:
        f, v, g, b, h, n

*** Error in `.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-11.2/8.2.2/bin/goursat': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00000000025bad90 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7f58d144b7e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8037a)[0x7f58d145437a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7f58d145853c]
.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-11.2/8.2.2/bin/goursat[0x40c168]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00c22000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 13250380                           /home/stla/Work/Haskell/opengl-implicit/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-11.2/8.2.2/bin/goursat
00c23000-00c43000 r--p 00822000 08:09 13250380                           /home/stla/Work/Haskell/opengl-implicit/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-11.2/8.2.2/bin/goursat
00c43000-00ce9000 rw-p 00842000 08:09 13250380                           /home/stla/Work/Haskell/opengl-implicit/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-11.2/8.2.2/bin/goursat
00ce9000-00ced000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
02275000-025dd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
4200000000-4200200000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
4200200000-14200100000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f58c4000000-7f58c4021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f58c4021000-7f58c8000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f58cb5ad000-7f58cc95e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f58cc95e000-7f58cc995000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 21242336                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtxc_dxtn_s2tc.so.0.0.0
7f58cc995000-7f58ccb94000 ---p 00037000 08:09 21242336                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtxc_dxtn_s2tc.so.0.0.0
7f58ccb94000-7f58ccb95000 r--p 00036000 08:09 21242336                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtxc_dxtn_s2tc.so.0.0.0
7f58ccb95000-7f58ccb96000 rw-p 00037000 08:09 21242336                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtxc_dxtn_s2tc.so.0.0.0
7f58ccb96000-7f58ccb9e000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 21234764                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpciaccess.so.0.11.1
7f58ccb9e000-7f58ccd9e000 ---p 00008000 08:09 21234764                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpciaccess.so.0.11.1
7f58ccd9e000-7f58ccd9f000 r--p 00008000 08:09 21234764                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpciaccess.so.0.11.1
7f58ccd9f000-7f58ccda0000 rw-p 00009000 08:09 21234764                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpciaccess.so.0.11.1
7f58ccda0000-7f58ccdab000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 21237495                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_radeon.so.1.0.1
7f58ccdab000-7f58ccfaa000 ---p 0000b000 08:09 21237495                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_radeon.so.1.0.1
7f58ccfaa000-7f58ccfab000 r--p 0000a000 08:09 21237495                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_radeon.so.1.0.1
7f58ccfab000-7f58ccfac000 rw-p 0000b000 08:09 21237495                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_radeon.so.1.0.1
7f58ccfac000-7f58ccfb3000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 21239163                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_nouveau.so.2.0.0
7f58ccfb3000-7f58cd1b2000 ---p 00007000 08:09 21239163                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_nouveau.so.2.0.0
7f58cd1b2000-7f58cd1b3000 r--p 00006000 08:09 21239163                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_nouveau.so.2.0.0
7f58cd1b3000-7f58cd1b4000 rw-p 00007000 08:09 21239163                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_nouveau.so.2.0.0
7f58cd1b4000-7f58cd1d6000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 21235062                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_intel.so.1.0.0
7f58cd1d6000-7f58cd3d6000 ---p 00022000 08:09 21235062                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_intel.so.1.0.0
7f58cd3d6000-7f58cd3d7000 r--p 00022000 08:09 21235062                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_intel.so.1.0.0
7f58cd3d7000-7f58cd3d8000 rw-p 00023000 08:09 21235062                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_intel.so.1.0.0
7f58cd3d8000-7f58cd3f1000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 9201712                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f58cd3f1000-7f58cd5f0000 ---p 00019000 08:09 9201712                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f58cd5f0000-7f58cd5f1000 r--p 00018000 08:09 9201712                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f58cd5f1000-7f58cd5f2000 rw-p 00019000 08:09 9201712                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f58cd5f2000-7f58cde20000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 21630454                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so
7f58cde20000-7f58ce01f000 ---p 0082e000 08:09 21630454                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so
7f58ce01f000-7f58ce06f000 r--p 0082d000 08:09 21630454                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so
7f58ce06f000-7f58ce078000 rw-p 0087d000 08:09 21630454                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so
7f58ce078000-7f58ce0df000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f58ce0df000-7f58ce0ee000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 21236496                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6.1.0
7f58ce0ee000-7f58ce2ed000 ---p 0000f000 08:09 21236496                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6.1.0
7f58ce2ed000-7f58ce2ee000 r--p 0000e000 08:09 21236496                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6.1.0
7f58ce2ee000-7f58ce2ef000 rw-p 0000f000 08:09 21236496                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6.1.0
7f58ce2ef000-7f58ce32f000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 21234507                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3.9.0
7f58ce32f000-7f58ce52e000 ---p 00040000 08:09 21234507                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3.9.0
7f58ce52e000-7f58ce532000 r--p 0003f000 08:09 21234507                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3.9.0
7f58ce532000-7f58ce537000 rw-p 00043000 08:09 21234507                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3.9.0
7f58ce537000-7f58ce814000 r--p 00000000 08:09 21238100                   /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
7f58ce814000-7f58ce819000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 21240658                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
7f58ce819000-7f58cea18000 ---p 00005000 08:09 21240658                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
7f58cea18000-7f58cea19000 r--p 00004000 08:09 21240658                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
7f58cea19000-7f58cea1a000 rw-p 00005000 08:09 21240658                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
7f58cea1a000-7f58cea1c000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 21241388                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
7f58cea1c000-7f58cec1c000 ---p 00002000 08:09 21241388                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
7f58cec1c000-7f58cec1d000 r--p 00002000 08:09 21241388                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
7f58cec1d000-7f58cec1e000 rw-p 00003000 08:09 21241388                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
7f58cec1e000-7f58cec36000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 9199541                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f58cec36000-7f58cee35000 ---p 00018000 08:09 9199541                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f58cee35000-7f58cee36000 r--p 00017000 08:09 9199541                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f58cee36000-7f58cee37000 rw-p 00018000 08:09 9199541                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f58cee37000-7f58cee3b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f58cee3b000-7f58cee4b000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 21237738                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0
7f58cee4b000-7f58cf04a000 ---p 00010000 08:09 21237738                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0
7f58cf04a000-7f58cf04b000 r--p 0000f000 08:09 21237738                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0
7f58cf04b000-7f58cf04c000 rw-p 00010000 08:09 21237738                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0
7f58cf04c000-7f58cf051000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 21243182                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1.0.0
7f58cf051000-7f58cf250000 ---p 00005000 08:09 21243182                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1.0.0
7f58cf250000-7f58cf251000 r--p 00004000 08:09 21243182                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1.0.0
7f58cf251000-7f58cf252000 rw-p 00005000 08:09 21243182                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1.0.0
7f58cf252000-7f58cf273000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 21234504                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
7f58cf273000-7f58cf472000 ---p 00021000 08:09 21234504                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
7f58cf472000-7f58cf473000 r--p 00020000 08:09 21234504                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
7f58cf473000-7f58cf474000 rw-p 00021000 08:09 21234504                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
7f58cf474000-7f58cf478000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 21243176                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0.0.0
7f58cf478000-7f58cf677000 ---p 00004000 08:09 21243176                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0.0.0
7f58cf677000-7f58cf678000 r--p 00003000 08:09 21243176                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0.0.0
7f58cf678000-7f58cf679000 rw-p 00004000 08:09 21243176                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0.0.0
7f58cf679000-7f58cf690000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 21243179                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0.0.0
7f58cf690000-7f58cf88f000 ---p 00017000 08:09 21243179                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0.0.0
7f58cf88f000-7f58cf891000 r--p 00016000 08:09 21243179                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0.0.0
7f58cf891000-7f58cf892000 rw-p 00018000 08:09 21243179                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0.0.0
7f58cf892000-7f58cf9c7000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 21240474                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
7f58cf9c7000-7f58cfbc7000 ---p 00135000 08:09 21240474                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
7f58cfbc7000-7f58cfbc8000 r--p 00135000 08:09 21240474                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
7f58cfbc8000-7f58cfbcc000 rw-p 00136000 08:09 21240474                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
7f58cfbcc000-7f58cfbcd000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 21243150                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
7f58cfbcd000-7f58cfdcc000 ---p 00001000 08:09 21243150                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
7f58cfdcc000-7f58cfdcd000 r--p 00000000 08:09 21243150                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
7f58cfdcd000-7f58cfdce000 rw-p 00001000 08:09 21243150                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
7f58cfdce000-7f58cfdd3000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 21236450                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
7f58cfdd3000-7f58cffd2000 ---p 00005000 08:09 21236450                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
7f58cffd2000-7f58cffd3000 r--p 00004000 08:09 21236450                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
7f58cffd3000-7f58cffd4000 rw-p 00005000 08:09 21236450                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
7f58cffd4000-7f58cffd6000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 21244691                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1.1.0
7f58cffd6000-7f58d01d5000 ---p 00002000 08:09 21244691                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1.1.0
7f58d01d5000-7f58d01d6000 r--p 00001000 08:09 21244691                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1.1.0
7f58d01d6000-7f58d01d7000 rw-p 00002000 08:09 21244691                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1.1.0
7f58d01d7000-7f58d01e8000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 21234448                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
7f58d01e8000-7f58d03e7000 ---p 00011000 08:09 21234448                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
7f58d03e7000-7f58d03e8000 r--p 00010000 08:09 21234448                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
7f58d03e8000-7f58d03e9000 rw-p 00011000 08:09 21234448                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
7f58d03e9000-7f58d0414000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 21242729                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0.0.0
7f58d0414000-7f58d0613000 ---p 0002b000 08:09 21242729                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0.0.0
7f58d0613000-7f58d0617000 r--p 0002a000 08:09 21242729                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0.0.0
7f58d0617000-7f58d0618000 rw-p 0002e000 08:09 21242729                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0.0.0
7f58d0618000-7f58d0619000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f58d0619000-7f58d061a000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 21243172                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1.0.0
7f58d061a000-7f58d081a000 ---p 00001000 08:09 21243172                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1.0.0
7f58d081a000-7f58d081b000 r--p 00001000 08:09 21243172                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1.0.0
7f58d081b000-7f58d081c000 rw-p 00002000 08:09 21243172                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1.0.0
7f58d081c000-7f58d0821000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 21243166                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1.0.0
7f58d0821000-7f58d0a21000 ---p 00005000 08:09 21243166                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1.0.0
7f58d0a21000-7f58d0a22000 r--p 00005000 08:09 21243166                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1.0.0
7f58d0a22000-7f58d0a23000 rw-p 00006000 08:09 21243166                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1.0.0
7f58d0a23000-7f58d0a25000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 21243169                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0.0.0
7f58d0a25000-7f58d0c24000 ---p 00002000 08:09 21243169                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0.0.0
7f58d0c24000-7f58d0c25000 r--p 00001000 08:09 21243169                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0.0.0
7f58d0c25000-7f58d0c26000 rw-p 00002000 08:09 21243169                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0.0.0
7f58d0c26000-7f58d0c28000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 21243154                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0.0.0
7f58d0c28000-7f58d0e27000 ---p 00002000 08:09 21243154                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0.0.0
7f58d0e27000-7f58d0e28000 r--p 00001000 08:09 21243154                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0.0.0
7f58d0e28000-7f58d0e29000 rw-p 00002000 08:09 21243154                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0.0.0
7f58d0e29000-7f58d0e4f000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 9175378                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.0
7f58d0e4f000-7f58d104f000 ---p 00026000 08:09 9175378                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.0
7f58d104f000-7f58d1051000 r--p 00026000 08:09 9175378                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.0
7f58d1051000-7f58d1052000 rw-p 00028000 08:09 9175378                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.0
7f58d1052000-7f58d11c4000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 21236799                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f58d11c4000-7f58d13c4000 ---p 00172000 08:09 21236799                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f58d13c4000-7f58d13ce000 r--p 00172000 08:09 21236799                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f58d13ce000-7f58d13d0000 rw-p 0017c000 08:09 21236799                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f58d13d0000-7f58d13d4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f58d13d4000-7f58d1594000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 9199553                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f58d1594000-7f58d1794000 ---p 001c0000 08:09 9199553                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f58d1794000-7f58d1798000 r--p 001c0000 08:09 9199553                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f58d1798000-7f58d179a000 rw-p 001c4000 08:09 9199553                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f58d179a000-7f58d179e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f58d179e000-7f58d17b4000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 9175104                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f58d17b4000-7f58d19b3000 ---p 00016000 08:09 9175104                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f58d19b3000-7f58d19b4000 rw-p 00015000 08:09 9175104                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f58d19b4000-7f58d1a33000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 21235792                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.3.0
7f58d1a33000-7f58d1c32000 ---p 0007f000 08:09 21235792                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.3.0
7f58d1c32000-7f58d1c33000 r--p 0007e000 08:09 21235792                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.3.0
7f58d1c33000-7f58d1c34000 rw-p 0007f000 08:09 21235792                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.3.0
7f58d1c34000-7f58d1c37000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 9199555                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f58d1c37000-7f58d1e36000 ---p 00003000 08:09 9199555                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f58d1e36000-7f58d1e37000 r--p 00002000 08:09 9199555                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f58d1e37000-7f58d1e38000 rw-p 00003000 08:09 9199555                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f58d1e38000-7f58d1e3a000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 9199560                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil-2.23.so
7f58d1e3a000-7f58d2039000 ---p 00002000 08:09 9199560                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil-2.23.so
7f58d2039000-7f58d203a000 r--p 00001000 08:09 9199560                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil-2.23.so
7f58d203a000-7f58d203b000 rw-p 00002000 08:09 9199560                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil-2.23.so
7f58d203b000-7f58d2042000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 9199571                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
7f58d2042000-7f58d2241000 ---p 00007000 08:09 9199571                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
7f58d2241000-7f58d2242000 r--p 00006000 08:09 9199571                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
7f58d2242000-7f58d2243000 rw-p 00007000 08:09 9199571                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
7f58d2243000-7f58d22b1000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 21627169                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
7f58d22b1000-7f58d24b1000 ---p 0006e000 08:09 21627169                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
7f58d24b1000-7f58d24b4000 r--p 0006e000 08:09 21627169                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
7f58d24b4000-7f58d24b5000 rw-p 00071000 08:09 21627169                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
7f58d24b5000-7f58d24b6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f58d24b6000-7f58d2523000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 21243193                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1.3.1
7f58d2523000-7f58d2723000 ---p 0006d000 08:09 21243193                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1.3.1
7f58d2723000-7f58d2724000 r--p 0006d000 08:09 21243193                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1.3.1
7f58d2724000-7f58d2725000 rw-p 0006e000 08:09 21243193                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1.3.1
7f58d2725000-7f58d282d000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 9176988                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f58d282d000-7f58d2a2c000 ---p 00108000 08:09 9176988                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f58d2a2c000-7f58d2a2d000 r--p 00107000 08:09 9176988                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f58d2a2d000-7f58d2a2e000 rw-p 00108000 08:09 9176988                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f58d2a2e000-7f58d2a54000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 9194210                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f58d2c08000-7f58d2c09000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f58d2c09000-7f58d2c11000 rw-s 00000000 00:05 63933                      /drm mm object (deleted)
7f58d2c11000-7f58d2c21000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f58d2c21000-7f58d2c22000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f58d2c22000-7f58d2c23000 rw-s 00000000 00:05 65766                      /drm mm object (deleted)
7f58d2c23000-7f58d2c2b000 rw-s 00000000 00:05 65763                      /drm mm object (deleted)
7f58d2c2b000-7f58d2c53000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f58d2c53000-7f58d2c54000 r--p 00025000 08:09 9194210                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f58d2c54000-7f58d2c55000 rw-p 00026000 08:09 9194210                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f58d2c55000-7f58d2c56000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffc9a6f7000-7ffc9a719000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffc9a74f000-7ffc9a752000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffc9a752000-7ffc9a754000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Abandon (core dumped)
```

Comment: Isn't this more a C question, rather than Haskell?

Comment: @leftaroundabout I don't know actually. When I remove the Haskell lines starting by `free`, something changes: I only get "segmentation fault" as error. There's no `malloc` and no `free` in the C code, as far as I remember.

Comment: Ah, so did you forget a word in the sentence “which I use in my code”?

Comment: There's a `free` function in Haskell. Anyway I will add the `C` tag, you're right.

Comment: I'm always falling over when something works on Windows but not on Linux....

Comment: This is a message from `libc.so`. It's related to memory corruption. If the code worked in other machine, I suspect from some 32-64 bits mismatch library or option.

Comment: This needs an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yeah. FWIW, I can reproduce the problem by running the linked code, so _Complete_ ✓ _Verifyable_ ✓, but _Minimal_ ✗.

Comment: @DanielWagner You could clone the repo. I don't see how I could minimize the code. There are only two modules generating some graphics.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thanks for having tested the package.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent 1. SO rules ask you to put the code on-site. Off-site code dumps are not allowed. 2. Are you really prepared to claim that the shortest possible program which causes an "invalid next size" error for the same reason this one does has over 500 lines each of Haskell and C? I bet you can get it down to just 20 lines including FFI/hsc2hs stuff. It's not each individual answerer's responsibility to reproduce the work of this minimization; that is wasted duplicate effort. The question asker is required to do it once and for all. (And you may even solve the problem in the process.)

Comment: @DanielWagner Indeed. I've just "solved" the problem by replacing a `malloc` with `mallocBytes (100000 * (sizeOf (undefined :: CTriangle))`. The problem is that 100000 is arbitrary, I don't know the size in advance. But now I have a better idea of the problem and I could ask a better question. Before that I was too lost for being more precise, sorry. I posted a CVE but not a "M"CVE. I know it's not the better appropriate way to get help but that could be enough in case if someone has encountered a similar error message.

Comment: @leftaroundabout The package should work now. Just in case you want to try it again. Cheers.